# How Deserialize data time for response handler REST TEMPLATE?

Tags: java, resttemplate

I am using ResponseErrorHandler interface to handle the server error and client error

I get this response from an external API
{
"timestamp": "2021-08-02T12:04:45.332+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Null Value Exception",
}

Now I have class where I am deserializing

```
public class ApplicationPayload {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    private HttpStatus status;

    private String error;
    
    private String message;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

```
@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {}
```

I am getting this error in handleError method

Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-08-02T12:04:45.332+0000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23

Comment: You are using a `LocalDateTimeDeserializer` in order to parse a `String` that includes an offset from UTC (the last 5 characters: `+0000`). A `LocalDateTime` cannot store information like that, you will have to use an `OffsetDateTime` here and a corresponding deserializer (I don't know if there's an `OffsetDateTimeDeserializer`, but if there is, use that).

Comment: Isn't that `OffsetDateTime` you have there, not `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Thanks I get your points, Is there a way to solve this issue? @deHaar

Comment: You might have to customise the one you have if there's no out-of-the-box `OffsetDateTime` deserializer. I'm hoping this is the API you're using, in which case there's an example [HERE](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/custom-json-serializer-and-deserializer-for-joda-datetime-objects/)